# Why isn't my Mongoose (findByIdAndUpdate) query updating in the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to push a string into an array into database entries found by their ID.  This is the put method itself:

```
app.put('/todo/:id', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:ObjectId(req.params.id)},
        { "$push": { "item": req.body } },
        { "new": true, "upsert": true },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("test");
        }
    ); });
```

The problem is, the log is never printed to console which makes me think this method isn't ever actually being called. I am assuming it has something to do with the front end part, where I call the put method on button submit, then?:

```
  $('form').on('submit', function(){

      var item = $('form input');
      var todo = {item: item.val()};

      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/todo/' + id,
        data: todo,
        success: function(data){
          location.reload();
        }
      });

      return false;

  });
```

Behavior wise, when I click the submit button, the text box clears (as it should), and changes the url to:

```
/todo/59bd48905a2ed911e0d480f2?item=item+to+be+inserted
```

Theres no errors logging in console. Where am I going wrong?

e:

Here's my schema, as well:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  item: [String]
});
```

Here's Url Encoded Parser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
```

Comment: **findByIdAndUpdate** expects just the **id** as the first argument. You can pass an object to match by _id using **findOneAndUpdate**.

Comment: @SteveHolgado Hm, even passing just the req.params.id didn't seem to help

Comment: I understand from what you are saying that the text box clears that that the success function is reached ? if that so, i see no response in the handler. Could the `urlencodedParser` middleware responed to the request and the callback of the  handler is never reached ?

Comment: Also, you are pushing **req.body**, which is an object, into **item** but in your schema, **item** is an array of strings.

Comment: No, the success function isn't reached, so I think it has something to do with the jquery. console.log("test"); is never reached, or logged in console.
@SteveHolgado Thanks, I've stringified it

Comment: Can you add a log before the query to check if the handler itself is reached ? And could you show the code of the `urlencodedParser` ?

Comment: @M.Sallam In the case of a log at the top of the put method, it still does not get called. I've edited in urlencodedParser, but it is using body-parser from npm

Comment: Ok so i have recreated your code and made only a couple of changes, passing the id straight as the first parameter and pushing `req.body.item` instead of `req.body` as Steve said and everything is working fine with no problems, so if that doesn't workout for you, please provide a more extensive version of the code as the problem might not be with the code provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so in the front end code you need to add preventDefault, And you have not defined the `id` variable. so this should work :

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var item = $('form input')
    var todo = {item: item.val()}
    var path = window.location.pathname.split('/')
    var id = path[2]
    console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: '/todo/' + id,
      data: todo,
      success: function (data) {
        // do something with the data via front-end framework
        location.reload()
      }
    })

    return false
  })
```

And in the server there is no need to stringify `req.body.item` :

```
app.put('/todo/:id', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,
      { '$push': { 'item': req.body.item } },
      { 'new': true, 'upsert': true },
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('here')
        res.end()
      }
    )
  })
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the help, this worked like a charm!